# INSERT and UPDATE not working after MySQL table name change but SELECT and DELETE work fine

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

After changing a table name using phpMyAdmin and then updating my code, INSERT and UPDATE queries do not work. I can perform the query in phpMyAdmin and as the title explains, DELETE and SELECT statements still work.. I'm certain my PDO prepared statement syntax is fine and the try block doesn't throw any errors. My immediate thought was my HTML input fields but I've been over these like 50,000 times. Any thoughts?

PHP code:

```
try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE signs SET sign = :sign, phonetic = :phonetic, definition = :definition, flag = :flag, modified = :modified WHERE sign_id = :sign_id');
        $stmt->bindValue(':sign_id', (int) $_POST['sign_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':sign', $_POST['sign'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':phonetic', $_POST['phonetic'], PDO::PARAM_STMT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':definition', $_POST['definition'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':flag', $_POST['flag'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':modified', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Definition updated successfully.';
        header('Location: 'dictionary.php');
        exit;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'An error occurred while connecting to the database.'.$e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage(), 0);
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="hidden" name="sign_id" value="<?= $row->sign_id; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sign
                                <input name="sign" type="text" value="<?= $row->sign; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Sign">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phonetic
                                <input name="phonetic" type="text" value="<?= $row->phonetic; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Phonetic">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Definition
                                <textarea name="definition" class="form-control" placeholder="Definition"><?= $row->definition; ?></textarea>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Flag
                                <select name="flag" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="0" <? if ($row->flag == 0) echo "selected"; ?>>None</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Try restarting the mysql server.

Comment: Your posted PHP code has an error: the "Location" line has three apostrophes: '

Comment: I doubt your query was ran. that's why It didn't throw errors

Comment: @Michael I modified that line before posting it here.

Comment: Man, are you sure you want to use "<?=" ? That thing's been deprecated and should not be used

Comment: @JuanBonnett [nothing is deprecated and it's all right to use](http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/short_tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing this line's third parameter:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':phonetic', $_POST['phonetic'], PDO::PARAM_STMT);
```

for

```
PDO::PARAM_STR
```

PHP Documentation says:

> PDO::PARAM_STMT (integer)
>       Represents a recordset type. Not currently supported by any drivers.

Comment: Doh! Looks like I relied on code completion for that one.